# How to display UIActivityViewController within UIAlertController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller, uialertcontroller

I have defined `UIActivityViewController` with my items, and now I need to display it within `UIAlertController` just like that:

[image]

What is the reason?

[image]

I would like to display this on iPad the same way like it is on the iPhone by default (from the bottom of my popover).

*For now my `UIActivityController` is displayed as a popover from `UIBarButtonItem`*

How to accomplish such effect?

I know that it is possible because Calendar works in the same way:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```